# Did rosjava break at most recent push?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error when building rosjava after I pulled just now:

```
:rosjava_bootstrap:jar
:rosjava_messages:generateSources
:rosjava_messages:compileJava
/home/tommy/my_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/generated-src/test_rosjava_jni/TestDataTypes.java:52: getByte() is already defined in test_rosjava_jni.TestDataTypes
  std_msgs.Byte getByte();
                ^
/home/tommy/my_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/generated-src/test_rosjava_jni/TestDataTypes.java:54: getByteV() is already defined in test_rosjava_jni.TestDataTypes
  java.util.List<std_msgs.Byte> getByteV();
```

Is there something I'm not seeing or is this a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37440/did-rosjava-break-at-most-recent-push?/) by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a regression. I've pushed a fix and added a test.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1